# Add variables to a transform script on a prefab, how-to?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I am able to Instantiate new objects at runtime and they spawn in with the correct scripts attached however the scripts do now spawn in with the variables fixed in their slots.

I need a way to spawn prefabs with the scripts attached AND the variable slots in the script are all filled in.
[image: The properties of the instantiated prefab]
[image: The properties of the original object]

Deploy capsule script (linked to main camera)

```
public class deployCapsule : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject CapsulePrefab;
    public Path path;
    public float respawnTime = 1.0f;

    void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine(capsuleWave());
    }

    private void spawnCap()
    {
        GameObject a = Instantiate(CapsulePrefab) as GameObject;
        a.transform.position = new Vector2(1.0f, 1.0f);
        path.followers.Add(a);
        Debug.Log("1");
    }

    IEnumerator capsuleWave()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(respawnTime);
            spawnCap();
        }
    }
}
```

Path Follower script

```
public class PathFollower : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float movementSpeed;
    //private float pathProgress = 0;
    public GameObject objectToSpawn;
    public Transform[] positionPoint;
    [Range(0,1)]
    public float value;

    void Start()
    {
        Debug.Log(iTween.PathLength(positionPoint));
    }

    void Update()
    {
        movementSpeed = 10f;
        if (value < 1)
        {
            value += Time.deltaTime / movementSpeed;
        }
        iTween.PutOnPath(objectToSpawn, positionPoint, value);
    }

    private void OnDrawGizmos()
    {
        iTween.DrawPath(positionPoint,Color.green);
    }
}
```

I KNOW THIS IS NOT TECHNICALLY POSSIBLE.
But I need a method to get this done one way or another.

I am quite new to unity and would appreciate any help given.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in deployCapsule, store a reference to the array of points

```
public Transform[] positionPoint;
```

assign the values in the inspector.

and then once you've instantiated the prefab, give it the array like this

```
//this is in the SpawnCap function
//GameObject a = Instantiate(CapsulePrefab) as GameObject;
a.GetComponent<PathFollower>().positionPoint = positionPoint;
//rest of your function
```

alternatively, set the values in the Awake() or Start() function of the newly instantiated Capsule by getting a reference to a class that has the data.

```
void Start()
{
    positionPoint = GameObject.Find("Spawner").GetComponent<deployCapsule>().positionPoint;
}
```

Comment: see now the problem is that the capsules do spawn with all the points assigned but they don't start travelling around the path

Answer (score 1):

After instantiating your capsule prefab and assigning a reference to it named `a` (I suggest you change this naming to something more logical)

```
GameObject a = Instantiate(CapsulePrefab);
```

Assuming your prefab already has the `PathFollower` component attached, you could use the `GameObject.GetComponent<T>` method to access it.

```
var pathFollowerComponent = a.GetComponent<PathFollower>();
```

After which, you could populate the `positionPoint[]` Transform's array (assuming that's what you're after) with references to the "Points" GameObjects located in the hierarchy and the scene.

It's up to you how to go about this:

- You could create a `tag` on each point, use `GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Point");`
- Obtain the children from the "PathFollower" `GameObject` and add its child transforms to your array
- Create a singleton instance or a "GameManager" class which stores the points located in a scene
- If you create new points dynamically, create a listener and invoke events to add the new points to the array whenever they're instantiated.

Note that the mentioned above may not return the points in the order you placed them, so you may need to sort them! In general, there are many other ways which you can find by searching the forums, or on Google!

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that your prefab is in project while the path nodes are in scene. You have two approaches to fix that.

First, your path nodes are under a parent object, that parent holds a container script:

```
public class PathNodes : MonoBehaviour
{
     [SerializeField] private Transform m_nodes;
     public Transform [] Nodes => m_nodes;
}
```

Either you use the singleton pattern (yes it is fine when used properly) or have the newly created object use FindObjectOfType then you can access the nodes.

The second solution is to have the prefab of your object to create in the scene as an inactive object. Being in the scene, you can then drag and drop all you need from the scene into it. The prefab is dragged in place of the original project prefab (CapsulePrefab) and when creating a clone of it, you just need to set it active.

Comment: see now the problem is that the capsules do spawn with all the points assigned but they don't start travelling around the path